# warning on type casting in C

Tags: c

In C, `strlen` returns a `unsigned long`.

I'm using an `int` variable to store it.  Why is there no warning?

Could someone give an explanation when it will be a warning and when it will not?

Comment: The return type of `strlen` is `size_t`.

Comment: Why would you not store it in an `unsigned long`, if that's what it `return`s?

Comment: C is not your mother like Java, that is what our teacher said :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C does not require any diagnostic when you assign a value of an arithmetic type `T1` to an object of another arithmetic type `T2`.

A lot of implementations issue an  informative diagnostic when you assign a literal value that does not fit in an object and in other cases but again it is not required by C.

Comment: So, the only issue is that I put an negative value to an unsigned variable?

Comment: @user3495562 a negative integer value has an arithmetic type and an unsigned integer type is also an arithmetic type. Do you think the compiler is required to issue a warning?

Comment: However, check this code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16bda4285d55f773 A warning is reported. But if I change `c` by strlen("hello"), no warning is reported.

Comment: @Peregring-lk this is added with `-Wextra` with `gcc` as an additional informative warning. It is not required by C.

Comment: I know, but why there's not a warning when comparing size_t with int, but when comparing unsigned with int?

Comment: @Peregring-lk because `-Wsign-compare` apparently does not warn when one operand is a constant like `int b = 4; if ((unsigned int) 3 == b`gcc`. With `strlen` function `gcc` is using builtin and  `strlen("hello")` is reduced to a constant, so you don't get the warning. Fool `gcc` so it cannot reduce it to a constant and you'll get the `gcc` warning: `strlen("hello" + printf(""))`.

Answer (score 3):

`C` is not strict on type safety so a conforming implementation may choose not to issue a warning.

Perhaps you can try some option with verbose warning, `-Wall` or similar for your compiler if you want the warning to avoid any such type-safety issue.

This is one of the pitfall of `C`, as if the value is larger than what `signed int` can represent, behavior is implementaion-defined.

**EDIT**

Quoting from **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>   Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is
>   converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the
>   maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value
>   is in the range of the new type.
>   Otherwise, the new type is signed and
>   the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
>   implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: *if the value doesn't fit in destination type, behavior is undefined.*  Assigning a value of an arithmetic type `T1` to an object of an arithmetic type `T2` is never undefined behavior. For example, `unsigned int a; a = -1;` is not undefined behavior.

Comment: *This is one of the pitfall of C, as if the value doesn't fit in destination type, behavior is implementaion-defined.* This is still not correct and it's not what C says. For example, `unsigned char b; b = 2 * UCHAR_MAX;` the value does fit in `b` but the assignment is perfectly defined, not implementation-defined.

Comment: @ouah Pedantic mode on: Assigning integral to unsigned has modulo behavior, to signed value preserving, bad things when not possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator this is not very clear to me, could you show an example of what could be for you an UB assignment ?

Comment: @ouah: `int x = UINTMAX;`. Though it seems implementation-defined signal is as far as it goes now...

Comment: @Deduplicator `int x =  UINT_MAX;` is implementation-defined behavior not UB, see the relevant quote in 6.3.1.3.

Comment: @ouah: Please look at my comments. I only had (incorrectly) written UB in my first message, but corrected it within a minute, and long before yours. Anyway, implementation-defined signal is plenty bad enough, don't you agree?